# Difference among different HTML Doctype Declarations

Tags: html

HTML Doctype Declarations are

1. Strict
2. Transitional
3. Frameset

Can someone explain me what is difference among them?

Answer (score 0):

[Checkout this article on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Introduction#Comments_and_doctype)  It has a very basic explanation of the various `doctype` options for beginners.

> In HTML 4.01, doctype referred to a DTD (Document Type Definition) as it was based on SGML.
>
> The **strict** DTD contained all HTML elements and attributes, but NOT presentational or deprecated elements (like font). Framesets were not allowed.
>
> The **transitional** DTD contained all HTML elements and attributes, INCLUDING presentational and deprecated elements (like font). Framesets were not allowed.
>
> The **frameset** DTD allowed frameset content and otherwise was the same as HTML 4.01 Transitional.

The current **HTML5** standard is to use `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

> this doctype tells the browser to interpret the HTML and CSS code according to W3C standards